Parallel implementation of Dijkstra: problem scaling with constant efficiency
I am learning about parallelization, but I am stuck on this problem: assume that you achieve a parallel efficiency of 70% for computing the shortest path for a graph with n = 20000 vertices on 16 processors and assume that you want to use a system with 32 processors. For how many vertices will you obtain the same parallel efficiency?
I am not sure how I can deal with this problem. Any help is appreciated

Is this a a theoretical question or a practical one? In practice, this is not possible to answer the question with the provided information for several reasons : 1. different architectures do not behave the same way (this include NUMA effects, big-little ones, the latency of atomics, etc.), 2. frequency scaling (including turbo boost) is dependent of the number of core enabled, 3. the actual cause of the reduced efficiency is unknown so the program may not scale at all beyond 16 cores, or may still scale a bit based on the actual cause (so the efficiency could be divided by 2 or not)

If this is a theoretical question (from university), I guess you should read the Amdahl's law and Gustafson's law (especially the later in this case).
